# Angular2 Reactive form dynamic groups of radio buttons

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a list of questions with radio buttons as answers. I do not know in advance the number of questions nor answers, but each question has its unique id. I am using getters for `answers` and `id` in the component class.

```
<div class="mb-2">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline" *ngFor="let answer of answers.controls">
      <input type="radio"
        id="{{id.value}}"
        name="{{id.value}}" <!-- This should be unique for each group -->
        [formControl]="answer.get('selected')"
        [checked]="(answer.get('selected').value == true)"
        class="form-check-input"
      <label class="form-check-label" for="{{id.value}}">
        {{answer.get('text').value}}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The component class methods:

```
  get answers() {
    return this.questionForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
  }
  get id() {
    return this.questionForm.get('id') as FormControl;
  }
```

When I select one answer, all radio buttons within the group are selected. However, the name is unique across groups but shared within the group. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For implementing reactive form you dont need to use html attibute
try to change your code like this

```
 this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
      'userData': new FormGroup({
          'username':new FormControl(null,[Validators.required]),
          'email':new FormControl(null, 
          [Validators.required,Validators.email]),
      }),
      'gender':new FormControl('female'), //This radio button
      'hobbies':new FormArray([])
    });
```

Check this Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind value of input and remove checked

```
   <input type="radio" value ="answer.get('selected').value"
    id="{{id.value}}"
    name="{{id.value}}" 
    [formControl]="answer.get('selected')"
    class="form-check-input">
```